# decimal to bin странно работает

Tags: javascript

мучался, мучался, родил этот код. если убрать условие в главной функции(не рекурсии), то после цифры 16 конвертер работает некорректно(его нужно реверсить)
сам код:

```html
let count = 0;
let array = [];
   
let rez;
let recurs = numbers =>
{
 rez = 0;
 if(numbers % 2 == 0)
 { 
  rez = numbers/2;
  array.push(0);
  if(rez > 1)
  {
  recurs(rez);
   
  }
  if(rez == 1)
  {
   array.push(1);
  }
  //console.log(rez);
 }
 if(numbers % 2 != 0)
 {
  rez = Math.floor(numbers/2);
  array.push(1);
  if(rez /1 > 1)
  {
   console.log("bam");
   recurs(rez);
  }
  if(rez == 1 && numbers != 1)
  {
   array.push(1);
  }
  



 }


 
  return array.reverse();
}

function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {  
count = 0;
array = [];
if(numbers < 16)
{
 return recurs(numbers);
}
else
{
 return recurs(numbers).reverse();
}
}
console.log(sumTwoSmallestNumbers(356));
```

Comment: А что программа делает? Какая задача?

Comment: @becouse превращать десятичное число в бинарное(двоичная система счисления)

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример функции - результат строка

```
let decToBinary = number =>
{
    if(number >= 1) {
      //Если не делится на два, то добавляем 1
      if (number % 2==1) {
        return decToBinary((number - 1) / 2) + 1;
      } else {

        return decToBinary(number / 2) + 0;
      }
    } else {

      return '';
    }
}
```

Функция - результат массив

```
let decToBinaryArr = number =>
{
    res=[]
    let recursion =  number =>{
    if(number >= 1) {
      //Если не делится на два, то добавляем 1
      if (number % 2==1) {
        res.push(1);
        return recursion((number - 1) / 2);
      } else {
        res.push(0);
        return recursion(number / 2);
      }
    } else {

      return 0;
    }
   }
   recursion(number);
   return res.reverse();
}
```